# WPF Databinding not working in both directions when DataGrid bound to Observable Collection of Properties with Sub properties

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

Excuse the wordy title, I'm having trouble with a succinct description. If I could come up with one, I could probably Google the right answer!

I am binding my DataGrid to an ObservableCollection of properties that themselves have properties.  My grid is populated just fine, but when I edit the grid the changes are not getting back to my model.
I have an  ObservableCollection

Normally, you'd just have some properties of MarriedCoupleRow, but I actually have something slightly more complicated.  Each MarriedCoupleRow has some propties (Male, Female) which in turn expose properties (Height, Weight, Information).  It's this Information that can be edited. Again, I can populate the grid just fine, but the setter property of Information is not hit when you edit the cell and tab off (or leave).

I'd appreciate any pointers or references, including how to better word my title!

Here's the simple code:

```
 public class XMLDemoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public XMLDemoViewModel()
    {

        _rows = new ObservableCollection<MarriedCoupleRow>();
        // create some data....
        for (uint i = 0; i < 2;i++)
        {
            MarriedCoupleRow row = new MarriedCoupleRow();
            row.Male = new HumanData();
            row.Male.Height = (70 + i*5).ToString();
            row.Male.Weight = 150+(i*30+1);
            row.Male.Information = row.Male.Height + " " + row.Male.Weight;

            row.Female = new HumanData();
            row.Female.Height = (60 +i*3).ToString();
            row.Female.Weight = 120+(i*10+5);
            row.Female.Information = row.Female.Height + " " + row.Female.Weight;
            _rows.Add(row);
        }
    }


    #region Fields

    private ObservableCollection<MarriedCoupleRow> _rows = null; 


    #endregion Fields

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<MarriedCoupleRow> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            return _rows;

        }

    }
    #endregion Properties
    #region Commands


    #endregion Commands

    #region Private Methods


    #endregion Private Methods
}

public class MarriedCoupleRow : ViewModelBase
{
    private HumanData _Male = null;

    public HumanData Male
    {
        get { return _Male; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Male)
            {
                _Male = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Male");
            }
        }
    }
    public HumanData Female { get; set; }

}

public class HumanData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public uint Weight { get; set; }

    private string _friendlyName;
    public string Information
    {
        get
        {
            return _friendlyName;

        }
        set
        {
            if (_friendlyName != value)
            {
                _friendlyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Information");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

And here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="XMLDemo.Views.XMLDemoView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="XMLDemoView"  Height="600" Width="1152">

    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <GroupBox Width="249" BorderThickness="2" Height="90">
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">Control</TextBlock>
                    </GroupBox.Header>
                    <Grid Height="64" Width="223">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    </Grid>

                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Male"  />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Male.Height}" IsEnabled="False"  Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Male.Weight}" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Male.Information, Mode=TwoWay}"   Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Female"  />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Female.Height}" IsEnabled="False"  Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Female.Weight}" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Female.Information}" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBox.Text bindings need to be set to updatesource on propertychanged.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Male.Information, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
```

There must be something goofy going on with LostFocus which is the default. I tested this using your code.

Comment: Thanks Lee O.!  I had the UpdateSourceTrigger on the <DataGrid ItemsSouce=...> line and thought that was enough. Clearly not!  Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Like your post. As I seen from the coding you are using Complex property binding with DataGrid. Also complex property changes won't be reflect in DataGrid.

However you can achieve this requirement in sample level. I will try to make the sample and let you know.

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I